# How to get rows written in Cyrillic / Russian in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, cyrillic

I have a SQL Server table which stores all the data across the world. But i want to retrieve only russian characters from table specifically.

I tried below query  but this is returning all NON ENGLISH data.

```
select * from tablename where column like '%[^-A-Za-z0-9 /.+$]%'
```

Is there a way to get only russian characters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to analyze one random (first for example) character from the string, if its code lays between first letter in the alphabet and the last.
For example like this:

```
select * 
from tablename 
where unicode(substring(column, 1, 1)) between unicode('А') and unicode('я')
```

and of course using this approach you do not get "all Russian characters", but you will be able to get all rows, where text is written in Russian. I suppose that is what you're really asking for :)